# insert content INSIDE the <p> tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to add some content  to the `<p>` after ipsum but before `<a>`

```
<p id="service">Service: lorem ipsum <a href="#">Change</a></p>
```

I want like

```
<p id="service">Service: lorem ipsum more content <a href="#">Change</a></p>
```

please let me know how to do.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://api.jquery.com/before/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#service>a').before(' more content ')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KnbDS/

Answer (score 1):

Its a 3 step solution:

1. Get the text inside the p tag
2. Edit the text, using substrings
3. Set the text inside the p tag to your newly formed string

EDIT:
As pointed out by several people jQuery already has this functionality (I learnt something new). So this is a much better route:

```
$('#service>a').before("new content");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
$('#service>a').before('Your extra code added by you')
```